# git - Determine origin/master without cloning?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get information from a remote git repository without cloning it?

Specifically, can I find out the current commit that a remote's master branch is pointing at, without cloning?

I'd like to do this so that I can loop through a bunch of repos and verify that my builds are all up-to-date in a quick way. I'm thinking that if I can just run a simple command against the remote git server, it would be faster than cloning the whole repository.

Assuming I have valid credentials, or it's a public server, is there something along the lines of:

`$ git show ssh://gitserver.com/path/repos/my-great-repo.git origin/master --pretty="%H"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git ls-remote` [command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) for that.
This will show you remote references with commit ID.
For your case the full command would be
`git ls-remote https://gitserver.com/path/repos/my-great-repo.git master`

Comment: Specifically, `git ls-remote <repository> master` shows the commit hash of the current master branch.